# I would like to fit a CARR model using the 'rugarch' package in R - what should I include in the specification?

Tags: r, statistics, finance

I know I have to specify a GARCH model for the square root of range without a constant term in the mean equation - just unsure how to apply this in the rugarch function.

Comment: Please, could you provide your code.

Comment: I suggest you to read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before to ask.